# How to change the default/user/profile form so the user can select one of the already created groups in auth_group table?

Tags: python, web2py

Well, pretty much what I have mentioned in the Title: I want to change the `default/user/profile` form so the user can select one of the already created groups in the `auth_group` table.  I tried adding the new fields I want to show in there, along with the *Role* field, in `db.py` like this:

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [
    Field('phone'),
    Field('id_role', 'reference auth_group', label='Role'),
    Field('description')]
```

However, after going to appadmin to reload the changes and going into `default/user/profile`, I can see the new fields but no menus or selection options for the *Role* field. Should I use another options in the Field Constructor?

I tried using `Field('id_role', 'reference auth_group.id', label='Role')` (note the ***.id***) and `Field('id_role', 'reference auth_group.role', label='Role')` (note the ***.role***), but only to see the same results...

How can you get something like what you got in `appadmin/insert/db/auth_membership`?

[image: screenshot of appadmin/insert/db/auth_membership]

(in the screenshot, *user id* and *group id*, just in case)

---

**Edit:**

@Anthony, I tried your approach - I created a new table called `responsabilidad` in a new db file called `db1.py`, like this:

```
db.define_table('responsabilidad',
                Field('nombre','string'),
                Field('descripcion','text'),
                format='%(nombre)s')
```

Note the `format` attribute in there. I saw what you said in the web2py manual:

> The format attribute will be used for two purposes:
>
> To represent referenced records in select/option drop-downs. ...

After that, I updated my `db.py` file, which is the one that creates the `auth_user` table, like this:

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [
                                          Field('telefono'),
                                          Field('responsabilidad','reference responsabilidad'),
                                          Field('descripcion')]
```

However, when I go to `/default/user/profile` (or `appadmin/insert/db/auth_user` for instance) I can only see the field in the Form, but not the drop-down menu that is supposed to be there...  Is there something else I should set or define to make this work?

[image: screnshot of /default/user/profile]

---

**Edit:**

Ok, I tried using tables other than auth_user.  I created an `usuario` table along with the `responsabilidad` table from the previous example, and have created/modified the following files:

```
//db1.py
db.define_table('responsabilidad',
                Field('nombre','string'),
                Field('descripcion','text'),
                format='%(nombre)s')

db.define_table('usuario',
                Field('nombre','string'),
                Field('id_responsabilidad', 'reference responsabilidad'))

//default.py
def test():
    form = SQLFORM(db.usuario)
    return locals()

//test.html
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=form}}
```

And now the form is displaying the drop-down menu as expected!

What I still don't understand is **why the form is correctly displayed now, but it won't if using `auth_user` instead of `usuario`**...

Comment: Are you sure you want to use auth_group for this purpose? Normally, auth_group (along with auth_membership) is used to assign permissions. This will allow users to set their own permission levels. Also, the design is intended to allow multiple group memberships (via the link to auth_membership), but you are allowing only a single group. Rather than hijack auth_group for use in this non-standard way, you might consider simply creating your own groups table, or even just using an `IS_IN_SET` validator to store the group role directly in the auth_user table.

Comment: @Anthony You are right, I was confused about how the auth_* tables should be used - actually, on what was the goal of those tables.  In my case, as you already discovered, I want to constrain the groups to just one per user, and allow the registered users to select the best group for them in their `profile` page.  I set a new table and tried to reference the new table, but somehow is not working as I expected.  Could you please advice?  Please check the last Edit in my question. Thanks!!

Comment: Make sure you call `auth.define_tables()` *after* you define `db.responsabilidad`. If your Auth definitions are in db.py, then `db.auth_user` will be defined first because model files are executed alphabetically, so db1.py will be executed before db.py.

Comment: @Anthony Right on target!  I renamed the file in where the definitions for the `db` object and `responsabilidad` were, and it worked perfectly.  Thank you very much, you rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a reference field, such as `Field('myref', 'reference other_table')`, if (a) `other_table` has already been defined and (b) `other_table` has a `_format` attribute, then the `myref` field will automatically get an `IS_IN_DB` validator and a `represent` attribute based on the `_format` attribute of `other_table`. The `IS_IN_DB` validator is what is responsible for generating the drop-down menu you are expecting.

The Auth tables are typically defined via `auth.define_tables()`. However, that results in the `auth_user` table being defined *before* the `auth_group` table, so if the `auth_user` table includes a field that references `auth_group`, that field will not automatically get the validator and `represent` attribute. In that case, you will have to specify those manually.

Comment: I tried this, but somehow I'm getting the Field label in there, but not drop-down menu.  I have edited my question, could you please advice?  Thank you very much - I'm fairly new using web2py, so I really appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: This works if I use a table other than `auth_user`.  I'm not sure why - I have added the details into the question.  Thanks :)

Comment: **This is the correct answer - please see the _edits_ to my question and comments to see the full resolution.**